# a question on permutations of coefficients of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

How to characterize all polynomials $ p(x) $ such that every polynomial obtained from $ p(x) $ by permuting the coefficients of $ p(x) $ has a root in common with $ p(x) $ (in some field extension)?

Comment: 
   I don't understand your last question. If $p(x)$ is a polynomial and $\sigma$ is an automorphism of its splitting field, do we not always have $\sigma(p(x))=p(x)$, so that
those two polynomials have all roots in common ?

Comment: ｆｏｒｇｅｔ　ｔｈａｔ　ｆｏｒｍｕｌａｔｉｏｎ　ｏｆ　ｔｈｅ　ｑｕｅｓｔｉｏｎ！！
Ｉｔ　ｉｓ　ｊｕｓｔ　ｔｏ　ａｓｋ　ｗｈｅｔｈｅｒ　ｐ（ｘ）　ａｎｄ　ｑ（ｘ）　ｈａｖｅ　ａｔ　ｌｅａｓｔ　ｏｎｅ　ｒｏｏｔ　ｉｎ　ｃｏｍｍｏｎ　ｗｈｅｒｅ　ｑ（ｘ）　ｉｓ　ｔｈｅ　ｐｏｌｙｎｏｍｉａｌ　ｗｉｔｈ　ｃｏｅｆｆｉｃｉｅｎｔｓ　ｅｑｕａｌ　ｔｏ　ｔｈｅ　ｃｏｅｆｆｉｃｉｅｎｔｓ　ｏｆ　ｐ（ｘ）ｕｎｄｅｒ　ｔｈｅ　ｉｍａｇｅ　ｏｆ　ａ　ｐｅｒｍｕｔａｔｉｏｎ　ｏｆ　ｃｏｅｆｆｉｃｉｅｎｔｓ　ｏｆ　ｐ（ｘ）？

Comment: I have tried and, I think, failed to understand the question. This may well be my fault, but I'm voting to close, pending clarification. 

Comment: Please use the "edit" link below the question, then write a more coherent question.  When you have done that, please flag for moderator attention so it can be reopened.

Comment: This question now has a meta thread: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/929/reopen-a-question-on-permutations-of-coefficients-of-polynomials/#Item_2

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the comment, we are to ignore the whole Galois group thing, and just talk about permuting the coefficients of $p(x)$, and whether the resulting polynomial $q(x)$ can have any common roots with $p(x)$. If $p(x)$ is irreducible then it can't have any common roots with $q(x)$ unless it equals $q(x)$. If $p(x)$ is not irreducible, well, $x^2+3x+2$ and $2x^2+3x+1$ share a root, it's not hard to construct other examples, it's not clear there's anything useful to be said about the situation. Permuting coefficients isn't "natural".

Comment: 
 Also, there's no relation between permuting coefficients and the solvability-by-roots thing.


Comment: I mainly agreed with Gerry Myerson except that permutting coefficients can be "natural" in some sense.
Consider a polynomial, p(x), of the ring F[x] where F is a field and its splitting field E over F. Along with p(x) we take into account the polynomial with roots as the coefficients of p(x), denoted by q(x) and its splitting field K over F.
Then for polynomials under our consideration we can express the roots of p(x) in terms of radicals of the coefficients of q(x). And hence we find a field extension of F such that E|F is a radical extension of K|F.
And I have found less nontrivial examples.

Comment: By non-trivial examples we shall understand that the roots of p(x) have expressions in terms of the coefficients of p(x) which are symmetric under the permutations of coefficients of p(x).
For instance, $ x^{2}+3x+2 $ is not a non-trivial example since it shares no common roots with $ 3x^{2}+2x+1 $.   

Comment: So, wait - you want $p$ to share a root with ${\it every}$ polynomial obtained by permuting its coefficients? Do you have an example of such a thing, other than $x^n+x^{n-1}+\dots+x+1$?

Comment: One example is given by the polynomial $ x^{3}+x^{2}-x-1 $ which shares one root 1 with every polynomial obtained by permuting its coefficients.

Comment: True - of course, that's true for any polynomial with 1 as a root, since it just says the coefficients add up to zero, which is unaffected by permutations. 

Comment: If all the coefficients are the same, we have one kind of solution. Otherwise we have at least two which are different. Choose a permutation which has these two (say $a$ and $b$) as coefficients of $x$ and the constant term. Swap the two by a transposition. Any common root has to be a root of the difference, which is $(a-b)(x-1)$ so $a=b$ of $x=1$.
Other transpositions (transpose two coefficients and take the difference) allow $x=0$ or roots of $x^m-1$, which would, of course, have to be roots of the original polynomial. But these roots would not survive all permutations.

Comment: I think you had solved completely the question.

Comment: Mark Bennet, may I suggest that you submit your comment as an answer so awllower can accept it and we can all move on? 